# The mapper returned a null Mono in a SpringBoot Reactive Router and Handler Unit test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-webflux

I have a functional router :

```
@Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> greetingRoute(Utilities utils,
                                                     AppConfig cfg,
                                                     GreetingHandler greetingHandler) {
        return RouterFunctions.route()
                .path("/api",api -> api
                        // x-headers validation
                        .filter((request,next) -> utils.verifyXHeaders(request,cfg,next))
                        // Customer urls
                        .nest(accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON),ops -> ops
                                // Greeting API
                                .GET("/v2/hello",greetingHandler::hello)
                        )
                        .build())
                .build();
    }
```

And it's handler function below:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> hello(ServerRequest serverRequest) {

        Mono<Greeting> greetingResponse = greetingSvc.greetingFunction();

        return greetingResponse.flatMap(greeting -> {
            BaseResponse brs = BaseResponse.builder()
                    .responseCode(String.valueOf(HttpStatus.OK.value()))
                    .responseMsg("Greeting")
                    .detailedMsg("Greeting Success")
                    .responseData(greeting)
                    .build();

            return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .bodyValue(brs);
        });

    }
```

I am trying to write a unit test for the handler as follows:

```
@Slf4j
class GreetingHandlerTest {

    GreetingSvc greetingSvc;
    WebTestClient client;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp(){
        this.greetingSvc = mock(GreetingSvc.class);
        Utilities utils = mock(Utilities.class);
        AppConfig cfg = mock(AppConfig.class);
        Greeting greeting = new Greeting("Hello Spring");


        GreetingHandler greetingHandler = new GreetingHandler(this.greetingSvc);

        when(this.greetingSvc.greetingFunction()).thenReturn(Mono.just(greeting));


        RouterFunction<?> route = new AppRouter()
                .greetingRoute(utils,cfg,greetingHandler);

        this.client = WebTestClient.bindToRouterFunction(route)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Get Hello Back")
    void testHello() {

        client.get()
                .uri("/api/v2/hello")
                .headers(Utilities.getHttpHeaders())
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectBody(BaseResponse.class);
        ;
    }
}
```

However this test always fails with an error `The mapper returned a null Mono` and the following stack trace:

```
12:46:14.282 [parallel-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.server.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter - [73a1446b] HTTP GET "/api/v2/hello"
12:46:14.334 [parallel-1] ERROR org.springframework.web.server.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter - [73a1446b] 500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/api/v2/hello"
java.lang.NullPointerException: The mapper returned a null Mono
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:228)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/api/v2/hello" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
        at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:228)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:125)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:282)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:863)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:282)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:863)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:431)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:219)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:201)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4490)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:451)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:219)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:201)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4490)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:451)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:219)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:201)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4490)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4490)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeWith(Mono.java:4605)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4457)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4393)
        at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.HttpHandlerConnector.lambda$doConnect$2(HttpHandlerConnector.java:98)
        at org.springframework.mock.http.client.reactive.MockClientHttpRequest.lambda$null$2(MockClientHttpRequest.java:124)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:45)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4490)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatIterable$ConcatIterableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxConcatIterable.java:147)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatIterable.subscribe(FluxConcatIterable.java:60)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4490)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeWith(Mono.java:4605)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4457)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4393)
        at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.HttpHandlerConnector.doConnect(HttpHandlerConnector.java:112)
        at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.HttpHandlerConnector.lambda$connect$0(HttpHandlerConnector.java:79)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:45)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4490)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.run(MonoSubscribeOn.java:126)
        at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:84)
        at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:37)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
12:46:14.346 [parallel-1] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.HttpHandlerConnector - Creating client response for  GET "/api/v2/hello"
12:46:14.351 [parallel-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions - [68105edc] [185decc2] Response 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
```

But testing the api on postman it responds with a success:

```
{
    "responseCode": "200",
    "responseMsg": "Greeting",
    "detailedMsg": "Greeting Success",
    "Data": {
        "message": "Hello, Spring!"
    }
}
```

Been stuck on this for a while now. How do I make this unit test pass by mocking the greeting service implementation. The Integration test also works by the way, am stuck on this unit test.

For more context `greetingSvc` implementation is here:

```
public Mono<Greeting> greetingFunction(){
        return Mono.just(new Greeting("Hello, Spring!"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was trying to mock the router params . In my case I replaced mocks for `Utilities` and `AppConfig` with real initialised objects as follows:

```
Utilities utilities = new Utilities();
AppConfig cfg = new AppConfig();
```

I updated my test to the following code and it passed.

```
@Slf4j
class GreetingHandlerTest {

    GreetingSvc greetingSvc;
    WebTestClient client;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp(){
        this.greetingSvc = mock(GreetingSvc.class);

        Utilities utilities = new Utilities();
        AppConfig cfg = new AppConfig();

        Greeting greeting = new Greeting("Hello Spring");


        GreetingHandler greetingHandler = new GreetingHandler(this.greetingSvc);

        when(this.greetingSvc.greetingFunction()).thenReturn(Mono.just(greeting));


        RouterFunction<?> route = new AppRouter().greetingRoute(cfg,utilities,greetingHandler);

        this.client = WebTestClient.bindToRouterFunction(route)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Get Hello Back")
    void testHello() {

        client.get()
                .uri("/api/v2/hello")
                .headers(Utilities.getHttpHeaders())
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectBody(BaseResponse.class);
        ;
    }
}
```